# spark how to set number of columns dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a file like this :

```
test057 - 192.168.1.12 - 00:11:22:33:44:57 - 2ZZ66-1 node 6 -  - test052 - 192.168.1.16 - 00:11:22:33:44:61 - 2ZZ66-1 Node2 -
test058 - 192.168.1.13 - 00:11:22:33:44:58 - 2ZZ66-1 node 5 -  - test053 - 192.168.1.17 - 00:11:22:33:44:62 - 2ZZ66-1 Node1 -
test_a001 - 192.168.100.10 - 1234.5678.0123 - AZZDEF -  -  -  -  -  -
test_b001 - 192.168.100.11 - 4321.1234.1234 - GHIJKL -  -  -  -  -  -
```

How Can I split it into 4 columns?

```
| name    |     ip        |     mac           |    tag         |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|    
|test057  | 192.168.1.12  | 00:11:22:33:44:57 | 2ZZ66-1 node 6 |
|test052  | 192.168.1.16  | 00:11:22:33:44:61 | 2ZZ66-1 Node2  |
|test058  | 192.168.1.13  | 00:11:22:33:44:58 | 2ZZ66-1 node 5 |    
|test053  | 192.168.1.17  | 00:11:22:33:44:62 | 2ZZ66-1 Node1  |
|test_a001| 192.168.100.10| 1234.5678.0123    | AZZDEF         |
|test_b001| 192.168.100.11| 4321.1234.1234    | GHIJKL         |
```

Comment: It is not clear how this question relates to apache spark. If you simply need to turn the raw data file into just four columns then I would suggest using a tool such as AWK with a column separator of " - "

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? What did you try? The delimiter is `<space>-<space>`. You can `split` on it and use `map` to get the first 4 elements?

Comment: the issue for me is that the each line consist of the 10 columns separates by "-".

Comment: This is the filling of Dataset:
Dataset<Row> df1Map = ds.select(functions.concat(ds.col("_c1")
                 ,lit(" - "), ds.col("_c2"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c3"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c4"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c5"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c6"),lit(" - ")
                 ,ds.col("_c7"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c8"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c9"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c10"),lit(" - "),ds.col("_c11")).as("text"))
                 .select(functions.regexp_replace(col("text"),"\n"," - "))
                .filter(col("text").like("%192%"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the file and then split by '-' and map the column to a class.

```
val ipFile = sc.textFile("file:////in_f/test/inpf.txt");
val ipSplit = ipFile.map(_.split("-"))
case class IP (name: String, ip: String, mac: String, tag: String)
val ipDF = ipSplit.map(x => IP(x(0),x(1), x(2),x(3))).toDF()
ipDF.select($"name", $"ip", $"mac", $"tag").take(4).foreach(println)
```

When you print the resultant output will look like below.

```
[test057, 192.168.1.12, 00:11:22:33:44:57, 2ZZ66] 
[test058, 192.168.1.13, 00:11:22:33:44:58, 2ZZ66] 
[test_a001, 192.168.100.10, 1234.5678.0123, AZZDEF]
[test_b001, 192.168.100.11, 4321.1234.1234, GHIJKL]
```

[image]

Comment: If Abhi respond to your question, please upvote his answer and mark it as solution.

Comment: I'm getting error:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
on Map stage.

Comment: I have updated the answer, where i missed a line. Please copy the code and retry.

Comment: Probably you can paste your code that you tried. The code above is working fine.